# Move Cursor Position in c#

Tags: c#, cursor

So I want like 2 Texboxes, where I can write the x and the y coordinate from the resolution of the monitor and if I click a specific key it hops to these coordinates and clicks the left mousebutton. Can someone help me?(I'm new and just learn in school but we never did something like this before)

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx

This is using the .NET framework.